# Do I need to explicitly release a contextual JDialog created with CDI?

Tags: java, swing, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, cdi

Suppose that `MyDialog` extends `javax.swing.JDialog`. Consider this code:

```
MyDialog dialog = CDI.current().select(MyDialog.class).get();
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.dispose();
```

**Questions:**

- Does it need to explicitly release `dialog` with CDI or the above code is already fine? If so, which class and method of CDI do I need to call? (Consider that after the user closes the dialog. I don't need it to be around anymore)
- According to the code, which context is `dialog` living in?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should explicitly release the bean. This is important because otherwise things like `@PreDestroy` won't work correctly. To release the bean you can use this code:

```
CDI.current().destroy(dialog);
```

The scope of the bean depends on the annotations you put on `MyDialog`. If you did not place any CDI annotations on the class, it will be `@Dependent` scoped. This means that you will get a new instance each time you call `.select(MyDialog.class).get()`.

Comment: Even though you may already answer my question in your comment, I'll ask you this dumb question anyway just to make sure: even if `MyDialog` has `@Dependent` scope and the code I showed is executed inside a method with a short lifetime, do I still need to release the bean by calling `CDI.current().destroy(dialog)`?

Comment: I think it depends on the CDI implementation whether this creates some sort of leak or not. In one of my applications I also didn't release beans in such scenarios without realizing it and it never caused any problems.